# Nmap 7.8 Assertion failed: htn.toclock_running == true

Tags: nmap

All of a sudden, nmap throws the following error after executing the canonical *sudo nmap -sP 192.168.109.** :

> nmap: Target.cc:503: void Target::stopTimeOutClock(const timeval*):
> Assertion  `htn.toclock_running == true' failed.

Tried to reboot PC, restart switch, router and grandma but none worked.

Nmap version is 7.8 on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: hey OP, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem (it seems it does). You can do this by clicking the tick mark below the votes. This helps us find the question more easily, as it will be marked as solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it states [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5866084.html), this bug has been solved in version 7.9.
Since via apt-get you won't get it (7.8 is the most recent on repo), I solved this by installing nmap via Snap as follows :

```
 sudo apt install snapd
 sudo snap install nmap
```

Check your new nmap version via :

```
sudo nmap --version
```

which should be the following :

> Nmap version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org )

If you get the following error when testing nmap :

> dnet: Failed to open device [device-name] QUITTING!

run the following :

```
sudo snap connect nmap:network-control
```

Cheers!